# jQuery syntax with multiple animations

Tags: jquery

I believe there is a syntax issue with the below code for the 'hover' animation does not seem to be working.  I would like jQuery to activate the class 'navigation_blob'. ps- i have included also in the html the jQuery easing plug-in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#jQueryFerrante > div').hide();

  $('#jQueryFerrante img').click(function() {
    $(this).next().animate({
      'height':'toggle'
    }, 'medium', 'easeOutBounce');
  });

$('<div id="navigation_blob"></div>').css({
  width: 0,
  height: $('#navigation li:first a').height() + 10
}).appendTo('#navigation');

$('#navigation a').hover(
  function () {// Mouse over function
    $('#navigation_blob').animate(
      {
        width: $(this).width() + 10,
        top: $(this).position().top
      },
      {
        duration: 'slow',
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        queue: false
      }
    );
  }, function() {// Mouse out function
    $('#navigation_blob').animate(
      {
        width: $(this).width() + 10,
        top: $(this).position().top
       },
       {
         duration:'slow',
         easing: 'easeOutCirc',
         queue: false
       });
    }
  );
});

  <div class="key-technical-skillsets">
      <h5>Key Technical Skill Sets</h5>
      <div id="navigation">
      <ol>
          <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Adobe Photoshop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
      </ol>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Typically syntax issues are revealed in the console. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: can you include the html

Comment: Did you include jquery ui library. Because easing function looks undefined when there is no jquery ui library.

Comment: The jquery ui library 'easing IS included.  No debugging as of yet for I still need a crash course on how to do it.